# Multiple keyboards with different configurations in Xorg

Tags: keyboard, xorg

I'd like to have different configurations for my laptop's builtin keyboard and the USB keyboard I attach and use at work.

Using Gnome's setup tools I've arrived at the following `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,se"
        Option "XkbModel" ","
        Option "XkbVariant" "caps:swapescape"
EndSection
```

Since the other keyboard has a completely different layout I don't want the `caps:swapescape`, so I added `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-typematrix.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "TypeMatrix Keyboard"
        MatchProduct "TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,se"
        Option "XkbVariant" ","
        Option "XkbOptions" ""
EndSection
```

(The value for `MatchProduct` matches what `xinput` lists my USB keyboard as.)

However, this doesn't have the desired result; both keyboards still end up with exactly the same configuration.

Is there some way to achieve what I want?

Comment: GNOME's keyboard plugin will gladly steamroll over any device-specific settings, and the ability to disable it was removed [a while back](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/commit/caf51f50f332aabe7af77f9641ac288dd88af553).

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following to your USB keyboard section, this way that section will apply to your specific USB device only:

`MatchUSBID  "1e54:2030"`

You can get the correct USB id of your TypeMatrix keyboard by doing `lsusb`.